# After logged on devise is called recursively to the index action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recursion, devise, action

The project worked well. I deleted it and downloaded from bitbucket and now I get this error
[error](http://pastebin.com/i1JiLDka)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the User model has a field called role . And this field was null....